# Not able to set auto increment value in my myql table using spring jdbc template

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have created a simple table with three columns, --> empid, name and location. Here empid has properties primary key, not null and auto increment.

When I set values using jdbctemplate it throws sql exception

`org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [insert into employees values(?,?)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

My code is as follows

```
@Override
public boolean addEmployee(EmployeeMO emp) throws EmiratesException {
    boolean isEmployeeAdded = false;
    try {
        String sql = "insert into employees values(?,?)";


        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[] { emp.getEmpName(), emp.getLocation() });


        isEmployeeAdded = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return isEmployeeAdded;
}
```

My total exception log is

```
PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [insert into employees values(?,?)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:99)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:870)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:931)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:941)
at com.emirates.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl.addEmployee(EmployeeDAOImpl.java:24)
at com.emirates.service.EmployeeServiceImpl.addEmployee(EmployeeServiceImpl.java:17)
at com.emirates.controller.EmployeeAddController.loginProcess(EmployeeAddController.java:33)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Why the empid is not setting properly? Any ideas

Comment: Shouldn't the SQL be "insert into employees (name, location) values (?,?)"?

Comment: @russianmario, yes you are right. My silly mistake

Comment: that is quite all right - we all make them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the names of the columns in your insert statement. The SQL should be:

```
insert into employees (name, location) values (?, ?)
```

From the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html):

> Specify the columns for which the statement provides values as follows:
>
> Provide a parenthesized list of comma-separated column names following the table name. In this case, a value for each named column must be provided by the VALUES list or the SELECT statement.
>
> If you do not specify a list of column names for INSERT ... VALUES or INSERT ... SELECT, values for every column in the table must be provided by the VALUES list or the SELECT statement. If you do not know the order of the columns in the table, use DESCRIBE tbl_name to find out.